# How to insert line numbers using Notepad2

Tags: notepad2

I am using Notepad2 in Windows for editing text files and I would like to add line numbers to the currently selected lines. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out the option "Edit -> Block -> Modify Lines... (Alt+M)" has the $(N) and $(0N) variables that can be used to add a line number